# Extract data from collections of type IEnumerable

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-objects

`BranchState` is a class which has the following properties:

- State
- Branch
- AgencyId
- Description

With this code...

```
var AgencyBranches = 
    from  b in BranchStates
    select  b.Description.Distinct();

var States = 
    from s in BranchStates
    select s.State.Distinct();

if (AgencyBranches.Count() == 1 && States.Count() == 1)
{
    if (States.FirstOrDefault().Tostring() == "CA") /// **This always yields some generic value.** 
        Response.Redirect("StateCA.aspx");

    if (States.FirstOrDefault().Tostring() == "Az") /// **This always yields some generic value.** 
        Response.Redirect("StateAz.aspx");
}
```

... `States.FirstOrDefault()` always yields `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char] ``

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not do what you think it does, because it's missing some parentheses:

```
var States = from s in BranchStates 
             select s.State.Distinct();
```

Here, `Distinct` operates in each `State` property value yielding a sequence of *characters* because `State` (a `string`) implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

You probably meant

```
var States = BranchStates.Select(b => b.State).Distinct();
```

Comment: Same for `AgencyBranches` (`Description`)